# Can I have a php function and javascript function with the same name?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, function, names

The php function validates user form details in the includes folder.

My javascript function validates user details in the javascript external source.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JavaScript on the client. They are different languages, each running in their own execution environment. They are completely independent, so yes, you can have functions with the same name.

Comment: thanks i wish i can give a +1 to felix but i can't vote.

Answer (score 31):

Of course you can. You can even give your pony the same name as any of the functions.

Comment: +1 for incorporating pony to the answer

Comment: You can even give your pony the same name as your car

Comment: Such a simple answer, to a simple question.  Pony makes it a +1

Comment: @zerkms lol, you make me laugh

Comment: @zerkms Great! I'll rename my parseHtmlWithRegex function to Tony then :)

Comment: This is true! My pony's name is `UrlRegexBasedValidator` and it works just fine!

Comment: one up before this all gets deleted :)